# 45GS02 (65CE02) stack high register

Tags: 6502

I was looking through some source for a 6502 cross-assembler and noticed that the extensions for the 45GS02/65CE02 (C65) have an oddity - while most of the new registers are set through the acc using TAZ/TZA etc., the stack base page register is set using Y, TYS/TSY.

I poked about, but I can't see a specific reason for this mentioned anywhere. My suspicion is that it was intended to allow the easy construction of large stacks by placing the base page in Y and then INY when needed. But it's also entirely possible that it was just easier to wire up internally.

Anyone have a documented answer on this?

Answer (score 3):

> Anyone have a documented answer on this?

No, but a good hint might be noting that already handled the (lower) stack pointer thru X, TXS/TSX. This was to allow stack pointer relative addressing by using ABS,X with ABS being $100 +/- the offset needed.

By keeping that scheme but using Y added flexibility by not cluttering X.

Comment: The TSX/TXS instructions of the 6502 long predated any stack-indexed addressing mode, unless the 6502 had one in early designs that was replaced by ZP,X mode.  I would think later processors would have used X as a transfer register for other things for consistency.

Comment: My guess is that the use of Y instead of X would have been motivated by a desire to allow a chunk of code to accept or return a 16-bit stack pointer in a pair of registers, though I'm curious how the amount of effort to special-case things like that compares with the amount of effort that would have been required to have all such instructions, including SP transfers, be capable of operating on either the X register or accumulator.

Comment: @supercat Mind to read? The 6502 has an ABS,X mode right from the start, so accessing data on stack is done by `TSX` followed by `OP $100,X`, or any higher base value for bytes above TOS.

Comment: The 6502 also has an ABS,Y addressing mode which would work essentially as well.  I guess the fact that the instruction decoding for INC and DEC only accepts 11ix x11x rather than 11ix xx1x, preventing those instructions from supporting ABS,Y mode, may have influenced the decision to use X, though I'm not sure what downside there would have been to having the decode ignore bit 2, allowing INC and DEC to support seven addressing modes instead of 4.  While TSX or TSY would be more useful for indexing purposes than TSA/TAS, the latter would be more useful for situations involving larger...

Comment: ...stack adjustments.

Comment: Minor thing: $101,X would be TOS (or better, INX then OP $100,X to handle a full stack).

Comment: Ahh Raff, I had not noticed the stack-offset addressing. I suspect that is indeed the reason. That way you could move through large stacks by INCing X and Y.